# My ImageView doesn't refresh

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to make an application that takes a picture and it display it on ImageView.

I succeded to make this but when I try to make a new picture the image from ImagaView is not refreshed.

**For example:** I push a button, an Intent to the Camera is created. I take **picture 'A'** which is saved on a file on the  **SD card** at path **'fileUri'**. Back in my activity mImageView1 shows the **picture 'A'**. Nice.It works.

I try to take a new **picture 'B'**, I call the Intent the picture is saved at same adress.The picture is corectly saved, but when I return in my activity mImageView1 shows the old **picture 'A'**.
Here is the code that changes the image of the ImageView:

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    ((BitmapDrawable) mImageView1.getDrawable()).setCallback(null);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    try{
        if(bImageSaved)
        {
            mImageView1.setImageURI(fileUri);
            mImageView1.postInvalidate();

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
         Log.e("Image2Notes",  e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

I tried different things to refresh the ImageView: `mImageView1.postInvalidate();` `mImageView1.draw(...);` without succes.

If you have a hint I will be greatefull.
Thank you,

Comment: I don't know if this is your only problem but `postInvalidate()` is for when you aren't on the `UI` thread. Use `invalidate()` if you are on the `UI` thread, which it looks like you are

Comment: Where do you change the file path to the new picture? You probably want to use `startActivityForResult()` then return the value and set the image in `onActivityResult()`

Comment: I called `invalidate()` with no succes. I already set the image in `onActivityResult()`. I checked the path, it is the same. I had a look to the picture. The picture on the SD card changed, it is the new picture, only in the ImageView is the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Start your camera activity for result using startActivityForResilt(). And then override function onActivityResult (). So that when your camera activity finishes onActivityResult () function will get called. There in that function you can change the image other than changing it in onResume (). Check the activity result status in onActivityResult ().

Comment: I already did this: `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
     mAplicationState=2;
    if (requestCode== CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
     if (resultCode== RESULT_OK) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n"+fileUri.getPath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      bImageSaved=true;
     mImageView1.setImageURI(fileUri);
      
     } 
    ....
`